# Contatenation and white space

Tags: python, concatenation

"Combining two strings using the + symbol is called concatenation.
Use the "hello" and "world" variables to get a "Hello World" string"

```
hello = "Hello"
world = 'World'

hello_world = hello + world

print(hello_world)      # Note: you should print "Hello World"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @rickyjoepr - I suspect that this is homework ... and that you are supposed to do it yourself.  (HINT!)  If not, then please explain what you problem actually is.

Comment: You should also tag the question with the language you're using.

Comment: hello = "Hello"
world = 'World'

hello_world = hello + ' World'
print(hello_world)      # Note: you should print "Hello World"

Comment: I apologize everyone, I thought I was in the python boards. I am doing the pycharm educational edition just for fun, and it is giving me a problem with the whitespace, it should be fairly simple. I dont know what I am doing wrong and would like to know, so that I may learn.

Comment: I am combining the two strings incorrectly and am not sure what is going wrong . I have tried different variations and keep failing, I know it is something I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you meant. Did it answer your question? @rickyjoepr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print "Hello World" with a space in between, simply do the following:

```
hello = "Hello"
world = 'World'

hello_world = hello + " " + world

print(hello_world)
```

Comment: You are awesome, I was fiddling with quotation marks for about three hours trying to get it right, I really wanted to know why I was doing it wrong, I am glad you helped me, because now I can move on and it wont happen again

Comment: Oh Great! I'm grad it helped. @rickyjoepr

Comment: You can indicate so by accepting the answer. Please see the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work     Welcome to Stackoverflow.  @rickyjoepr

Answer (score 0):

```
world = 'World'
hello_world = ' '.join((hello, world))
print(hello_world)
```